# Name for an operation on matrices?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $a \times n$ and $b \times m$ consider the following operation $A \dagger B$ whose result is an $a b^n \times n m$ matrix. $A \dagger B$ is a block matrix with $a$ blocks $(A \dagger B)_{i,j}$ of size $b^n \times n m$ each constructed as follows. For each vector $j \in \{1, \dots, b\}^n$ create a row $(A_{i,1} \cdot B_{j[1]}, A_{i,2} \cdot B_{j[2]}, \dots, A_{i,n} \cdot B_{j[n]})$ where $B_t$ is the $t$-th row of $B$.

Is there a name for this matrix operation?

Comment: How is this operation arising? Or are you hoping to call it the "Yaroslavtsev super-slam"?

Comment: I just need the fact that $rank(A \dagger B) = rank(A)rank(B)$ which is easy to show directly. However, it would be helpful to know if this operation and its properties are already known so that I can just cite an appropriate source. I like your "super-slam" idea though :)

Comment: I'm in favor of the yaroslavtsev super-slam. You can cite this MO question:)

Comment: If you just need rank multiplicativity, there is a more economic one - tensor product (of size $ab\times nm$, with $(A\otimes B)_{\langle i,k\rangle,\langle j,l\rangle}=A_{i,j}B_{k,l}$)

Comment: Thanks, just for the rank argument tensor product is definitely enough, I was just wondering about the matrix itself.

Comment: As a starter, one needs an operation on vector spaces something like $V^{\otimes W}$ of dimension $\dim(V)^{\dim(W)}$; of course with chosen bases it is immediate, but is there an invariant version?

Comment: I've posted [a question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/219630/41291) about the latter

Comment: Thanks. I should have fixed this earlier but can't edit the comment. The multiplicativity of rank only holds as an inequality $rank(A \dagger B) \ge rank(A) rank(B)$.

Comment: what are these $B_{j[1]}$, $B_{j[2]}$, etc?

Comment: Treating j as an $n$-dimensional vector $j[t]$ is its $t$-th entry.